# Optimal Threshold On Single Input

Tags: logistic, classification, threshold

Suppose we have a sensor that measures "how red" an object is. Using this single input, we would like to classify whether or not the object is round. We have a data set comprised of tuples where the first element is the quantity describing "how red" something is and the second element is 1 for round and 0 if not round.

Example data set:

```
 "how red" | Round?
----------------------
     3     |     0
     255   |     1
     43    |     0
```

My friend decided that she wanted to use a threshold on the "how red" input feature to determine whether or not an object is round to the best of her ability. She used this feature and label to train a logistic regression classifier, determined a threshold on the output of the sigmoid function that maximized her F1 score, and then used that threshold to solve for a corresponding value of "how red". She uses this value of "how red" as a threshold to identify if objects are round or not. Does this approach make sense? Why does/n't this approach make sense?

To me, the right and simple approach would have been to pick a threshold on the single input feature that maximized the F1 score rather than trying to model the relationship between the input variable and label with an affine transform + a nonlinear transform while maximizing F1 ... then solving for the threshold.

To be more clear, I will write the approach my friend took below.

**Friends Method**

```
log_reg.fit(x=data['how_red'], y=data['is_round'])
sigmoid_out = log_reg.predict(data['how_red'])
# find threshold on logistic regression output that maximizes F1 score
lr_thresh = findLRThreshold(sigmoid_out)
# Given the fitted model and the threshold that maximizes F1 score
# solve for the corresponding value of 'how_red'
how_red_thresh = findHowRedThreshold(lr_thresh, log_reg)
```

The function *findHowRedThreshold(lr_thresh, log_reg)* solves for the value of $x$, a value of how_red, in the equation below since all other variables are defined: 
$$lr\_thresh = \frac{1}{1+e^{-(w0*x+b)}}$$

Comment: I don't really understand the differences in approaches, can you show the code if you have it?

Comment: I wrote some pseudo-code for my friends method. Let me know if anything is unclear. :)

Comment: I believe the two approaches are actually the same, since the sigmoid function affects a monotonic transformation of redness.  You are correct that if your only objective is a decision rule, directly determining the redness threshold is sufficient.  There are reasons to prefer the model based appoach however.  Having an estimated probability for each level of redness can allow you to compute the probabilities of events you may care about in the wider context of the problem.

Comment: Good point. However, I am still a bit confused. I agree that both the affine transform and sigmoid function are monotonic, but we are trying to maximize the F1 score not just the sigmoid function. That being said, is F1 score monotonic? To simplify matters, I think we can think about whether precision and recall are monotonic first since it is a requirement that they must be in order for F1 to be.

Comment: IMO, I don't think prec or rec are monotonic as a function of their input (x,y), hence F1 is not monotonic. Therefore, maximizing F1 score after applying logistic regression is not equivalent to maximizing F1 based on just determining a threshold via a decision rule.

Comment: I have the same problem, was thinking about using a 
varying threshold on the independent var. then plot the roc curve a check the best performance (and the respective threshold). Did you find an answer?